# feed awk positional parameters

Tags: bash, awk

Can someone please help me with a script that takes a list of integers and returns a response with the average, total, maximum and minimum values?

I need to be able to pass parameters when I run the script e.g:

```
./script.sh 1 2 3 4 5
```

I have an awk script that does the average, total and maximum sorted, I just need to add a bit so that it will read the arguments - so when I run `./script.sh 1 2 3 4` it returns:

```
Average: 3
Min: 1
Max: 5
Total: 16
```

Any help would be appreciated.

This is what I have already:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk 'NR == 1 { max=$1; min=$1; sum=0 }
        { if ($1>max) max=$1; if ($1<min) min=$1; sum+=$1;}
        END {printf "Min: %d\nMax: %d\nAverage: %d\nSum %0.0f\n", min, max, sum/NR, sum}'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey CRM, I probably do not. but that is the tree I started barking up first so just went with it.  oguz ismail has answered my question and it worked perfect, so ill carry on with the awk perspective.  Thanks for chipping in though, C J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
printf '%s\n' "$@" | awk ...
```

Answer (score 2):

In bash, you could do the same logic with a loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# == 0 ]]; then
    echo "No arguments provided. Expected integer args. E.g. $0 1 4 6 "
    exit 1
fi

max=$1
min=$1
avg=0
total=0

for i in $@; do
    [[ $max < $i ]] && max=$i
    [[ $min > $i ]] && min=$i
    total=$((total + i))
done

# Using bc program as bash doesn't support floating point math.
avg=$(echo "scale=6; $total/$i" | bc)
echo "max: $max, min: $min, avg: $avg, total: $total"
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
printf '%s\n' "$@" | 
awk '
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    sum+=$i
    min=min<$i?min?min:$i:$i
    max=max>$i?max:$i
  }
  print "Avg="sum/NF ORS "min="min ORS "max="max ORS "Total="sum
}'
```

Comment: As always - parentheses around your ternary expressions would greatly improve readability. White space would help too. I'd have to think for a while about what `min=min<$i?min?min:$i:$i` might mean while `min=(min<$i ? (min ? min : $i) : $i)` is much clearer.

Comment: @EdMorton, sure sir will do it and let you know then here sir.

Answer (score 2):

Your awk script can be simpler if you just sort the input:

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/env bash

printf '%d\n' "$@" |
sort -n |
awk '
NR==1 { min=$0 }
{ sum+=$0; max=$0 }
END { printf "Average: %d\nMin: %d\nMax: %d\nTotal %0.0f\n", (NR ? sum/NR : 0), min, max, sum }
'

$ ./script.sh 1 2 3 4 5
Average: 3
Min: 1
Max: 5
Total 15
```